# what is the easiest way to keep a question/answer on hold until ready?

Tags: support

If preparing a question or answer takes time what would be a best way to save a temporary copy without releasing it?

Comment: You could use our  [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex answers.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/242)

Comment: Do I understand that, that is a public sandbox?

Comment: Yes, it is public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three main options, as far as I see it:

1. You can keep a copy in your harddrive;
2. you can email that to yourself;
3. or better yet, use the email drafts to edit and add more.

Comment: Be careful with drafts, they don't seem to be 100% reliable.

Comment: @Bill: I meant the email drafts, I have clarified that. Of course the site draft system is far from being reliable.