# Feature request: Save Question (and Answer) as Draft option

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes a question pops into my mind a mere 5 minutes before I have to run an errand.  In that situation, I can either: (a) write the question down on paper and ask it later, or (b) ask the question very quickly, but perhaps with errors that later need editing.  I generally choose (a), which isn't altogether that inconvenient.

> But is there any way that we could have a "Save Question as Draft" option?  I think many users would find it very convenient.

Aside from the rushed scenario I mentioned above, there are also many times when my thoughts aren't fully clear, or my phrasing could be ironed out.  It would be nice to be able to begin writing a question without feeling as if it's a final draft. (I know that there are "edit" options, but one never wants to edit too much...)

**And** given all the recent discussion about the quality of questions on this site, perhaps such a mechanism would encourage users to wait a little longer before posting.

Update: Hm, I see that there's also [this sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers) for drafts of answers.  Otherwise, it seems that the best options for saving questions/answers are mentioned on [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6351/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-keep-a-question-answer-on-hold-until-ready).

Comment: Write it as an answer to any question, then go when you have to leave. The draft "answer" will be saved: if you go back to the question you answered, your draft answer will still be there, and you can copy it into a question when you have time to finish.

Comment: @gnometorule: Assuming your computer isn't prone to crashing, sure, that's a fine workaround. Still, I'd like to request this feature regardless. For instance, I've found that saving e-mails as drafts to be very convenient. Why not have the same here?

Comment: I also think it would be cool to have a separate place for half-formed questions or answers -- ones that might take more than a day or two to finish. Personally, I'd rather not keep a half-formed question/answer occupying a tab on my computer for too long.

Comment: It was more meant as a hint. To get a feature done isn't exactly certain, and in the meantime, I thought this might be helpful.

Comment: Of course. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: There's also option (c): copy the draft question to a text file and save it on your computer. (As it happens, that's what I'm doing right now...)

Comment: I think this is a good idea.  I would like to see more people asking well written questions.  This would be a (somewhat subconcious) incentive to improve your draft instead of posting carelessly and editing after being criticized.

Comment: In my experience, it automatically saves what you type in the question field.  For example, I just opened the "Ask Question" page, typed a bunch of words and gave it a title, then closed my browser.  When I opened the browser back up, it was still there...

Comment: I really want the feature to save questions as drafts. Sometimes, I write a lengthy question, but get demotivated over time and don’t finish it. Then I save it on my computer and never look at it again. But I certainly would if I was bored for a second and could then easily browse my drafts instead of searching for them, copying them etc.

Comment: I saw your post when I requesting the same feature..

Comment: I'd also be very interested in being able to save multiple drafts, as I often work on different problems simultaneously.

Comment: I lost my an hour work by clicking on stupid refresh button :(