# asking a question with a complicated formula

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to save a question before submitting it? Sometimes a question may involve several complicated formulae which takes time to complete. It would be useful if you could prepare a question but save it to go over in detail and submit at a later time.

Comment: Some past discussions which might give useful tips how to do this (off-site): [what is the easiest way to keep a question/answer on hold until ready?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6351) and [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4735) (And also other posts linked there.)

Comment: There were also some feature requests similar to this one on this meta: [Is there a save draft feature when asking a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10396) and [Feature request: Save Question (and Answer) as Draft option](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8687).

Comment: get a latex compiler write it up in that and post it once complete ?